# iOS: Playing video that needs authentication works in QuickLook but not in MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsurl, nsurlcredential

I login to my server using a `SOAP web service`. Once logged in, many of the files that I am viewing are only available to the logged in user, so iOS must create a session in `NSURL` or something.

When trying to preview a video file using `MPMoviePlayerViewController` it will not work, it just loads up the viewController, then dismisses it.

If I use `QuickLook` it does work, probably because I download the video locally first, then view it.

But, I don't want to do it this way, I want to stream the video using `MPMoviePlayerViewController` because I don't want the user to have to download an entire video file.  I have seen posts about using `NSURLCredential` but that doesn't seem to work for me.  I used (added my own personal info obviously):

```
/**
 * Play media session
 *
 * @version $Revision: 0.1
 */
- (void)playMediaWithURL:(NSString *)mediaURL {

    // Authenticate
    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"myusername"
                                                             password:@"mypassword"
                                                          persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

    NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc]
                                             initWithHost:@"mysite.com"
                                             port:80
                                             protocol:@"http"
                                             realm:nil
                                             authenticationMethod:NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault];

    [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] setDefaultCredential:credential forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];

    // The movie player
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[mediaURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *tempPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:movieURL];

    // Add observer
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
         addObserver:self 
         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
         name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

    // Properties
    tempPlayer.moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay = YES;
    tempPlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    tempPlayer.moviePlayer.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:tempPlayer];
    [tempPlayer.moviePlayer play];

}//end
```

Since this video is only viewable by a logged in user, if the video URL is accessed by a public user, they are presented with an HTML form to login. Does `NSURLCredential` not work in this case?

Why do all calls to `NSURLConnection` work, using my logged in credentials (such as downloading the video), but `MPMoviePlayerViewController` doesn't seem to use those same credentials, and refuses to play the video (probably because it gets the login page)?

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: +1 for good question - curious on the answers. Generally speaking, MPMoviePlayerController (just as AVPlayer which the former relies on) do not seem to make much use of such shared, high-level networking functionalities.

Comment: I am using one of my iOS dev support tickets and sent this question off to Apple. Will see what they say..

Comment: Yeah, they said that it wouldn't work because I have a normal HTML form login, rather than HTTP auth.

Comment: Are you able to fix this problem Nic ? I'm facing the same problem now.

Comment: Nope. Even submitted a support ticket to Apple. They said it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I had a similar problem not being able to pass cookies to MPMoviePlayerController. I found from stack overflow that the solution is to use NSURLProtocol. Still, it was painful figuring out how to do it, so I thought I'd save people some time by sharing the coded solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23261001/3547099