# MPMoviePlayerViewController cannot play video although passed authentication

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I got this error when trying to view a video using MPMoviePlayerViewController. The video url worked fine on Safari browser but not on iPhone/iPad.

```
NSConcreteNotification 0x122b9ab0 {name = MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification; object = <MPMoviePlayerController: 0x12243330>; userInfo = {
    MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey = 1;
    error = "Error Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-11829 \"Cannot Open\" UserInfo=0x122bc190 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open}";
```

Using Charles proxy, I can see there requests:

```
Status  Complete
Response Code   401 Unauthorized
Protocol    HTTP/1.1
Method  GET
Content-Type    text/html
```

then

```
Status  Complete
Response Code   206 Partial Content
Protocol    HTTP/1.1
Method  GET
Content-Type    video/mp4
```

then

```
Status  Complete
Failure Client closed connection before receiving entire response
Response Code   206 Partial Content
Protocol    HTTP/1.1
Method  GET
Content-Type    video/mp4
```

same problem here [iOS: Playing video that needs authentication works in QuickLook but not in MPMoviePlayerViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790697/ios-playing-video-that-needs-authentication-works-in-quicklook-but-not-in-mpmov)

Comment: After testing on real device, I didn't get that error message but the MPMoviePlayerController show and dismiss immediately. Result from console log:
NSConcreteNotification 0x209df5f0 {name = MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification; object = <MPMoviePlayerController: 0x20966630>; userInfo = {

    MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey = 0;

}}